# How can I efficiently add a variable value to a combined range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Adding a value to a combined range in VBA

I am trying to add a variable value to a range, which consist of multiple ranges. Using "for each cell" is super slow and takes forever. I managed to use this code successfully when the range is not consisting of multiple ranges, now, using a combination of ranges, the macro finishes without errors - but looking at the cells I am trying to change, there is a #VALUE error.

```
Sub rangecheck()

Dim x As Long
Dim number_of_tenants As Long
Dim range_names() As String
Dim ranges() As Range
Dim dynamic_range As Name

number_of_tenants = 5
ERV_change = 0.1

ReDim range_names(1 To number_of_tenants)
ReDim ranges(1 To number_of_tenants)

    For x = 1 To number_of_tenants
    range_names(x) = "range" & x
    Set ranges(x) = Range("F" & 21 + 172 * (x - 1) & ":AJ" & 21 + 172 * (x - 1))
    Set dynamic_range = ThisWorkbook.Names.Add(Name:=range_names(x), RefersTo:=ranges(x))
    Next x

Set combined_range = Range("range1")
    For x = 2 To number_of_tenants
        Set current_range = Range("range" & x)
        Set combined_range = Union(combined_range, current_range)
    Next x
    
combined_range.Value = Evaluate(combined_range.Address & "+" & CStr(ERV_change))

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you edit this question to show what you're trying to do? Maybe with a before and after screenshot? Are you just trying to add 0.1 to each of the range cell values?

Comment: You can add anything to a value of one cell but not to ADD in value of multiple cells (range)  Try> Range("A1").value = Range("A1").value & " !!!"  it works, but this Range("A1:A2").value = Range("A1:A2").value & " !!!"  not working. The code has and other problems eg. RefersTo:=ranges(x)  ==> RefersTo:="=" & ranges(x).Address

Comment: Why not add `ERV_change` to each block as you perform the first loop?  That should still be pretty fast.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ: The problem in your example is not that you cannot get or set the value of multiple cells at once but that you cannot concatenate an array and a string. `Range( "A1:A2" ).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose( Array( "a", "b" ) )` works fine while `Debug.Print Array( "a", "b" ) & "c"` gives an error.

Comment: Hi @z32a7ul, in my example I say "...but not for ADD to multi-cell value..." and the addition is: (Range("A1:A2").value & " !!!") I didn't say " set' or 'get'. The addition is what you describe as "cannot concatenate an array and a string". I completely agree with you and with your comment I think my example becomes clear.

Answer (score 1):

As @TimWilliams mentioned the following is pretty fast: On my machine it took 2.94 seconds for 5000 tenants, whereas your code took 109.52 seconds. Furthermore, it took 9.09 seconds when the naming line is uncommented.

```
Sub rangecheck()
  Dim start As Double: start = Timer
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  
  Dim x As Long
  Dim number_of_tenants As Long:  number_of_tenants = 5
  Dim ERV_change As Double:       ERV_change = 0.1
  Dim row_offset As Long:         row_offset = 21
  Dim sht As Worksheet:           Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("enterSheetNameHere")
  
  For x = 1 To number_of_tenants
    With sht.Range("F" & row_offset & ":AJ" & row_offset)
      .Value = Evaluate("=" & sht.Name & "!" & .Address & "+" & ERV_change)
      '* If you have to name the ranges then uncomment the following line
      '.Name = "range" & x
    End With
    row_offset = row_offset + 172
  Next x
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

  MsgBox "Time taken: " & Format(Timer - start, "0.0000")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following corrections to your code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub rangecheck()
    Dim ERV_change As Double: ERV_change = 0.1
    Dim number_of_tenants As Long: number_of_tenants = 5
    Dim range_names() As String: ReDim range_names(1 To number_of_tenants)
    Dim ranges() As Range: ReDim ranges(1 To number_of_tenants)
    
    Dim x As Long: For x = 1 To number_of_tenants
        range_names(x) = "range" & x
        Set ranges(x) = Range("F" & 21 + 172 * (x - 1) & ":AJ" & 21 + 172 * (x - 1))
        Dim dynamic_range As Name: Set dynamic_range = ThisWorkbook.Names.Add(Name:=range_names(x), RefersTo:=ranges(x))
    Next x
    
    Dim combined_range As Range: Set combined_range = Range("range1")
    For x = 2 To number_of_tenants
        Dim current_range As Range: Set current_range = Range(range_names(x))
        Set combined_range = Union(combined_range, current_range)
    Next x
    
    Dim a As Long: For a = 1 To combined_range.Areas.Count
        Dim temp() As Variant: temp = combined_range.Areas(a).Value
        Dim r As Long: For r = LBound(temp, 1) To UBound(temp, 1)
            Dim c As Long: For c = LBound(temp, 2) To UBound(temp, 2)
                temp(r, c) = Val(temp(r, c)) + ERV_change
            Next c
        Next r
        combined_range.Areas(a).Value = temp
    Next a
End Sub
```

Note that the `Range` object has an `Areas` property, which consists of multiple `Range` objects, if the `Range` in question was created with the `Union` function as in the case of `combined_range`. The `Value` of each of these is a two dimensional array, which can be retrieved and overwritten at once.

If you try to simply read or write `combined_range.Value` that is the same as reading or writing `combined_range.Areas(1).Value`.

So you have to iterate over this `Area` property. However, inside each of these, all cells will be written with one call between VBA and Excel, therefore this will produce the best available performance in this situation, better than the "for each cell" solution you understandably want to avoid.